# Is it possible to run an Aggregate function with a Where clause inside a union query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

When I try to add this field (Avg_Run_TimeX (1-14)) to the Union, it gives me a syntax error, missing operator inside query expression. I think this is because it reads and executes the Davg function correctly until it hits the Criteria (I reference the Access ID field inside the WHERE clause of that function). Below will be the relevant SQL for a *small* part of the Union as well as the Query that is the source this issue.

Union SQL:

```
SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1 AS 
Current_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1 AS Date_Scheduled,
Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.Avg_Run_Time1 AS Historical_Avg_Run_Time, Tbl_RunTime.Run_Time1 AS 
Projected_Run_Time, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1 AS Date_Ran,
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped, Qry_ScheduledItems.Access_ID, "01" AS Union_Line
FROM ((Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number) LEFT JOIN Qry_TimeCollectionAvg ON
Qry_JobTicket.Access_ID = Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.Access_ID) LEFT JOIN Tbl_RunTime ON 
Qry_JobTicket.Access_ID = Tbl_RunTime.Access_ID
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Is Not Null) AND 
((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) 
Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null))

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2 AS 
Current_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2 AS Date_Scheduled, 
Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.Avg_Run_Time2 AS Historical_Avg_Run_Time, Tbl_RunTime.Run_Time2 AS 
Projected_Run_Time, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2 AS Date_Ran, 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped, Qry_ScheduledItems.Access_ID, "02" AS Union_Line
FROM ((Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = 
Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number) LEFT JOIN Qry_TimeCollectionAvg ON 
Qry_JobTicket.Access_ID = Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.Access_ID) LEFT JOIN Tbl_RunTime ON 
Qry_JobTicket.Access_ID = Tbl_RunTime.Access_ID
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Is Not Null) AND 
((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) 
Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null));
```

Query SQL:

```
SELECT Qry_TimeCollection.Access_ID, Format(Nz([Historical_Run_Avg1],"0"),"hh:nn:ss") AS
Avg_Run_Time1, DAvg("Historical_Run_1","Qry_TimeCollectionAvg","Access_ID =" & [Access_ID])
AS Historical_Run_Avg1, Qry_TimeCollection.Historical_Run_1 FROM Qry_TimeCollection;
```

*Edit:* This is the portion of the Query that I believe is the source of the error. `DAvg("Historical_Run_1","Qry_TimeCollectionAvg","Access_ID =" & [Access_ID]) AS Historical_Run_Avg1` My error message when running the union is this:
[image: Error Message]

*Edit2:* To start from the beginning - We collect times for each run of a part number, based off of start and stop time to get the total time elapsed. I then am trying to average the total time for each unique part so we can have a moving average of time taken across all runs. I have gotten it to take and work with single run values, but calculating an average and then inserting it to the Union seems to be the source of my problem. Perhaps I should be calculating the Averages elsewhere and inserting it to a table, to then pull in a 'Raw' value instead of this calculated one? Desired Output would look like: (Where Historical_Avg_Run_Time is a double number(2.77777777777778E-05) but formatted as Time "h:nn:ss") This is because this double gets multiplied by Quantity/PCS to get total Runtime for this specific Job.

| Access_ID | Part_Number | Historical_Avg_Run_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 76808-704 | 0:00:02 |
| 2 | 76808-705 | 0:00:01 |
| 3 | 76808-706 | 0:00:04 |

Comment: Please reduce your question to the minimum query that shows the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: @Andre Done, this is as minimal as I can keep them while also keeping their structure. I highlighted where I think the issue is stemming from just a few minutes after the post was created as well. I am not necessarily even looking for a specific solution, just to know if structurally if what I am trying to do is possible, or if there are recommendations about going at it from another angle.

Comment: You are not showing UNION, just normal individual queries which look fine. But to directly respond to question in title, the answer is Yes. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Why are you using domain aggregate instead of SQL aggregation?

Comment: @June7 The Union select statement doesn't change past that, the only difference is the Numbered fields go up one. I am on the way out of the office currently but I will update tomorrow with sample data and desired output. The short answer is I am using domain because I built the query through Query Builder UI, but also it is the way I am more familiar with. If you think going SQL aggregation route will work out better in the long run (or maybe even fix this error?!) then I see no reason to not make the change. *Edit:* The overall Union isn't a problem, just this interaction with this Query.

Comment: Domain aggregate function in query or textbox causes slower performance. If speed is issue, use SQL whenever possible. `Access_ID` is a number type field?

Comment: @June7 Speed isn't necessarily an issue here but I will keep that in mind. And yes, `Access_ID` is the PK autonumber field that our Part data is related by. I have updated to show desired output, but sample data is a bit harder. I am not sure which portion of data would be most useful in helping, a barebones run of the updated union SQL or a look into the Qry_TimeCollectionAvg where I actually calculate out the moving Avg?

Comment: I cannot evaluate this without data. Tests in my database work. Consider posting in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours. The error you cite is often caused by lack of delimiters for text or date field, but you say Access_ID is number and delimiters are not required. Is UNION query named Qry_TimeCollection?

Comment: @June7 The Union is named Qry_UnionAll. It is used for separating out our Operations fields into various Schedules or Reports. All it does is make each record split into however many Operations it has so that I can query one field for criteria instead of 14 (as well as things like Date Scheduled, Date Ran, Time Difference all go from 1-14). Qry_TimeCollection is just some of the relevant Part Data, and all of the Raw Times our production team puts in when running. Then I do the calculating total time, and the moving average inside Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.

Comment: I cannot help. This is too complex without data to work with - query based on query based query. I am confused by the UNION pulling from same query (Qry_TimeCollectionAvg) as the DAvg(). I am not understanding where the UNION triggers DAvg(). Yes, temp table might be best approach.

Comment: @June7 The Union pulls in Davg when it references the field Qry_TimeCollectionAvg.Avg_Run_Time1. I am assuming because that is the field which performs the Davg function. I am going to try the Temp table approach, I don't see of another way to access the raw data without the Union going a bit crazy hitting the Davg Criteria. Thank you for trying to help me through it though! I don't know where I would be without some of you very helpful folks on this site lol.